# Dependencies don't seem to work in my autostart folder

Tags: python, selenium, dependencies, autostart, autorun

I made a simple python script that requires having the chrome webdriver in the same folder to run.
When I run the script myself it works but when I put it in the autostart folder it acts like the chrome webdriver isn't there.
I tried using a vbs file to run it in a different location but it doesn't make a difference.
I'm guessing that files from the autostart folder get called from elsewhere and that I need to put the webdriver there, but where is that place?